# Multi Desktop with Ubuntu 10.04 and the Catalyst Control Center

Tags: 10.04, multiple-monitors, radeon, ati

I have Ubuntu 10.04 installed on my laptop, with an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3670. I would like to connect this to an external monitor and use multiple desktops, as opposed to a single extended desktop.

I have tried selecting "Display Manager -> Multi Display -> Single display desktop (Multi-desktop)" and rebooting. This does give me two desktops, but after I move my mouse from the first desktop to the second desktop I can not move it back, and there appears to be no way to switch between the desktops.

I have read that people suggest enabling "Display Options -> Xinerama" but as far as I understand this would not dynamically adjust the set up depending on whether I have an external desktop connected.

I need a solution that will let me easily transition between one and two desktops as I often transition between using one and two screens (laptop + external monitor).

The "Single display desktop (Multi-desktop)" setting would be appropriate, if only I could figure out how to switch between these desktops.

Some people have mentioned using open source graphics drivers instead - is this likely to solve the problem? I assumed that the propriety drivers would be better.

Comment: I originally had the fglrx driver from the Ubuntu repositories, however this was a few versions behind the drivers on the AMD site, so I have manually installed Catalyst 12.4 following these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI. While I did get the drivers to work, I still have the issue of not being able to move my mouse between desktops when "Single display desktop (Multi-desktop)" is enabled.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am able to move my mouse cursor from the first desktop to the second, but once it's on the second desktop I can not move it back to the first. Occasionally dialogue windows will open on the first screen instead of the second, and I am able to enter keyboard input (e.g. the admin password box will show on the first desktop, but I am still able to enter my password and press enter).

Comment: This question is over 5 years old and addresses 10.04 which is long past EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.